# Query can not be executed, or waiting too long

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL 5.0 and working with some crowded tables. I actually want to calculate something and 
wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT 
   shuttle_payments.payment_user as user, 
   SUM(-1 * (shuttle_payments.payment_price + meal_payments.payment_price ) + 
   print_payments.payment_price) as spent 
FROM 
   ((shuttle_payments 
   INNER JOIN meal_payments ON shuttle_payments.payment_user = meal_payments.payment_user) 
   INNER JOIN print_payments ON meal_payments.payment_user = print_payments.payment_user) 
GROUP BY 
   shuttle_payments.payment_user 
ORDER BY 
   spent DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Well, there are 3 tables here and have approx. 60,000 rows per table. Is it taking too long because tables are so crowded (so should I transfer to NoSQL or sth) or it is a normal query but my server is taking too long because its CPU is weak? Or my query is wrong?

I want this query to *sum all price columns* from three tables and found which user spent the most money.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: State your expected output.

Comment: I edited, it's now stated in the last sentence.

Comment: you should add index for payment_user col

Comment: 60k isn't all that big, however with this query, it does need to read and collate all tables to get the result of this. A different database implementation will need to do the same thing. In addition to the answer. Look at the `EXPLAIN {query}` ([explain](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/sql-syntax.html#explain)) had to check it existed then. If anything restore from a backup to a newer MySQL version and see if that's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your query is Ok. You have to check whether there are indexes present on these three tables or not.
Please create indexes like-

```
CREATE INDEX idx_shuttle_payments ON shuttle_payments(payment_user);
CREATE INDEX idx_meal_payments ON meal_payments(payment_user);
CREATE INDEX idx_print_payments ON print_payments(payment_user);
```

Above statements will create non-clustered indexes on `payment_user` column.

if `payment_user` data type is `BLOB/Text` then -

```
CREATE INDEX idx_shuttle_payments ON shuttle_payments(payment_user(100));
CREATE INDEX idx_meal_payments ON meal_payments(payment_user(100));
CREATE INDEX idx_print_payments ON print_payments(payment_user(100));
```

In above statements, I have set `prefix length` to 100. You have to decide this prefix length as per your data.

From MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html):

> BLOB and TEXT columns also can be indexed, but a prefix length must be
>   given.

Comment: I do get an error like this: `#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'payment_user' used in key specification without a key length`

Comment: It seems like `payment_user` column data type is `text`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Query time became like 5 seconds, it wasn't event computing back then. Thank you.

Comment: appending `payment_price` to the above 3 indexes would also gain some time. As would changing from `text` back to a `varchar` of sufficient length for the users.